# Compatible laptop with port replicator

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, laptop, lenovo, docking

Has anybody got Ubuntu running on a modern laptop with a USB3.0 port replicator? Specifically running additional monitors.

I want to move my work machine away from a desktop to a docked laptop. And I don't want to have to plug in power, keyboard, mouse, monitors and net every morning.

I've been looking at two machines:

1. [Lenovo ThinkPad 440s](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t440s/)
   The Linux compatibility looks good but according to forums the USB3.0 dock display doesn't work, and the manufacturer has no interest in making it work. I hear better things about the USB2.0 replicator but I don't know if it works with this PC
2. [Dell Precision M3800](http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/precision-m3800-workstation/pd)
   Dell have a "baby brother" to this with official Ubuntu support and I've read this one works well too. The recommended dock is also USB3.0 and I can't find any info on Linux support for it. No response from Dell either

I'm open to other options but I do need lots of RAM and lots of SSD. I'd love to hear from anyone who has something like this working. If I can't find a solution soon I'm going to have to buy a Mac. And I really don't want to do that!

Answer (score 0):

In the hopes that this is still relevant, if not for you then for somebody else:

I personally have a T440p and I am using an UltraDock with 90W power supply. I cannot tell anything about the Dell model.

### Dock display support

You are required to install a [firmware update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?DocID=HT081248) for the dock using Windows, to make the dock display work with Linux. There is a [patch on the way](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71267) to make the dock compatible even with the older, buggy firmware.

One (1!) external monitor works fine connected to the dock. You can NOT use more than one, as the proper [support for Display Port Multi Stream Transport hubs](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72795) is missing in Linux. When connecting multiple monitors to the dock, the output is cloned on all of them.

However, you can add an additional monitor by connecting it via VGA to the notebook directly. You would have to plug that manually. when un/docking.

### Dock audio support

You need to do [some fixing](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.alsa.devel/116657) to make the docking station audio jack work.

### Dock USB support

No issues.

### Other (Linux) issues

More info is well documented in a [github wiki page](https://github.com/leoluk/thinkpad-stuff/wiki/Haswell-ThinkPad-problems) of user leoluk.